# POST OBJECTs using AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code but I am unable to access the content of the objects passed using ajax. What am I missing?

```
$(".submit").click(function(){ 
  var fruits = {"fruits" : ["apples","banana","oranges"]};
  var cars = {"cars" : ["BMW", "Honda", "Toyota"]};
  var my_Obj = fruits + cars;
  mydata = JSON.stringify(my_Obj); 
  $("#mydata").val(mydata);
  $.ajax({
    url: "add.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      name: $('#name').val(),
      Address: $('#Address').val(),
  my_obj : $mydata
    }, 
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (status) {
      if (status.success == false) {
        alert("Failure!");
      } else  {
        alert("Success!");
      }
    }   
  });
}); 


  <form id="json" method="post" action="add.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="Address" value="">
    <input type="text" name="mydata" id="mydata" hidden>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="send">
  </form>
```

add.php

```
$new_post['id'] = $_POST['id']; 
$new_post['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$new_post['address'] = $_POST['address']; 
$new_post['my_obj'] = $_POST['mydata'];
print_r ($new_post);
```

[my_obj] displays [object Object][object Object].
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have a variable called `mydata`, but then you try to use it as `$mydata`, which isn't the name of the variable.  PHP variables prepend a `$`, but in JavaScript that's just another character as part of the variable name, so you're using an undefined variable.  When you debug this, what is the actual POST being sent to the server?  You can capture that in a browser debugging tool (like Firebug) to see what's being passed.

Comment: Additionally, $mydata and mydata are potential (may be intentional) global leaks. Once you get the other problems sorted out, you'll probably also find that `fruits + car` doesn't do what you mean. Since you're using jQuery, you'll probably want to read up on jQuery.extend (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong that I see:

1, The form can be submitted by clicking enter, so i would use a `.submit()` method rather than 'submit.click()':

```
$('form').submit(function(){
});
```

2, The form will submit unless you `return false` in your `.submit()` method

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // all of your code
    return false;
});
```

3, In `add.php` you need to return `json` information:

```
echo json_encode($new_post);
```

4, You are not setting `status` in `add.php`

```
$new_post['status'] = true; // or false depending on what your trying to do
```

Hopefully this will give you a start.

****Note:** This does not take into account the vars that you are sending to `add.php`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send raw objects via a form submit, you need to flatten them to text first. This is done via serialization, and the simplest way to do it is via JSON, since it is understood on both the client and most server languages out of the box.

In your case , replace the my_obj part in the AJAX call with: my_obj: JSON.stringify(my data)

Comment: still got the same result [object Object][object Object]